# Маска телефона на андроиде не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сделал чат на сайте, но некорректно работает маска. Код простой:

```
//маска телефона в чате
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#shout_name").mask("+7(999)999-99-99");
    $("#shout_name").attr("placeholder",'+7(999)999-99-99');
});
```

На пк и айфоне она работает корректно. Прикрепляю скриншот
[image: alt]

Но на андроиде она работает иначе.
Прикрепляю скриншот
[image: alt]

Как пофиксить?вот ещё окно ввода

```
<input type='text' name='shout_name' id='shout_name' class='form-control' maxlength='30' placeholder="+7(999)999-99-99" />
```

Comment: Какой андроид? И если заменить `type='text'` на `type='tel'` - работает?

Comment: Любой телефон с ос андроид, если я устанавливаю тип tel, то на всех устройствах нормально, а на андроиде когда начинаю вводить вторую цифру перекидывает в конец и вводит последнюю цифру

Comment: А если ещё maxlength убрать?

Comment: Убрал максимальную длину всё равно, первую цифру вводишь нормально, а вторая уже в самом конце вводится даже попробовал максимальную длину 16 ставить, всё равно не то

Comment: На 9 всё без изменений норм работает в хроме. А какая версия плагина?

Comment: Вот что у меня подключено <script src="/java/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/java/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/java/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/java/fancybox.min.js" ></script>

<script src="/java/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/java/jquerymaskedinput.js"></script>
<script src="/java/visiwig.js"></script>
<script src="/java/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

Comment: Опа спасибо за наводку, оказалось конфликтовали скрипты закомментировал этот {*<script src="/java/jquery.js"></script>*} и всё ок